# Render offline frame in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want to transfer Qt application image in real time to another device.
So i need to render the MainScreen widget with all its contents, and pass it as a bitmap to some communication channel.

I want to minimize number of calls to **render** because it is CPU expensive, but i also want to be able to pick all changes in the UI.

So i tried to put the **QWidget->render** command inside the **paintEvent**, but it caused recursive repaint error.

What is the optimal way of grabbing the application frame without errors of recursive repaint?

Comment: is [QWidget::grab](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grab) not what you are looking for?

Comment: This is another function to grab a frame, but as i mentioned the problem is in timing of its activation. Activate it by timer can cause missing events in case if the timer is slow,  or too much overhead in case the timer is too fast.  Activation from paintEvent causes recursive repaints error.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best solution but you could break the recursion by skipping the `render()` call if it has already been called.

```
void paintEvent() {

   ...

   if(! m_rendering) { // m_rendering must be class member variable
      m_rendering = true;
      render();
      m_rendering = false;
      return;
   }

   ...

}
```

But note that you will only render if `paintEvent()` of the `MainScreen` is called. So you are likely to miss the repaintings of a child widget. You may solve this by using a `QTimer` controlled `update()` call .. depending on the frame rate you need.

Comment: This may be the possible solution, i'll try it.